# How would you test google maps?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I came across this in an java interview earlier. It was one of the only question I wasn't able to answer merely through lack of familiarity with google maps integration.

Can anybody let me know what would have been a model answer? Research from google searches point me to Selenium but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track?

p.s I'm not sure whether I posted this question in the correct manner but apologies in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is a fine example. Check out some of their example videos. Selenium is basically a way to test an application without having any access to its innards.

Either way, I'm sure there would be a follow up question with more specifics, so play around with it to get a feel for what it does.

Comment: Thanks very much @normalocity. I will have a look. The question was  literally posed like that and Im wondering whether i was expected to elaborate on the methodology in doing so.